# I've powered off and on my Ubuntu instance on Scaleway and now pinging the IP timeouts, and so does SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, boot, ping, cloud

I used to connect through SSH into the instance and do my thing.

They needed to update the private IP of the instances and I had to just turn off and on the instance in order for that to happen.

Once I did that, I couldn't SSH anymore - it just hang until I received a timeout.

*Pinging the instance using the IP also timeouts.*

They have a "rescue" boot image and I'm able to boot and mount the volume myself in order to investigate, but I don't know what to look at or what to do to make the instance be able to boot normally and work.

There wasn't anything fancy in there, just a mongo DB, a small node application, and a Let's Encrypt Certificate.

**Details:**

`> uname -a`

`Linux ... 4.4.127-mainline-rev1 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 10:38:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Excerpt from their informing email:

> During this maintenance, your server will be powered off, then powered on on another physical server. This operation will cause a downtime of a few minutes to an hour, depending on the size of your local storage. The public IPv4 will not change at migration, but the private IPv4 and the IPv6 will be modified due to technical limitations.

> No specific actions are required on your side. *However, if the maintenance date does not suit you, you can perform the migration yourself by powering off, then powering on your instance before our intervention.* **[that's what I did]** At restart, it will be located on another physical server with no immediate maintenance need.

Comment: What did you do to "update the private IP"? Do they have a way to get to the "console" without using ssh? The fact that you can't ssh or ping strongly suggests that the network configuration is wrong. This will be simplest to investigate from the console. You might be better off backing up your application and creating a fresh instance.

Comment: @icarus I had to do nothing. I just powered off and on the instance as recommented by them. I added an excerpt from their email in the question body.

Comment: I would take this up with scaleway. If you use their "rescue image" do you connect via ssh, and if so is it the same public ip address that you use when things are working?

Comment: @icarus I've taken it with them, it's been a terrible and useless experience.

When I use the rescue image, I still use the same public IP, yes.

By the way, `cat /etc/fstab` says "UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM", if it matters in any way...

Comment: The fstab message doesn't matter. I would compare the contents of /etc/network/interfaces between the rescue and "installed" images. You haven't mentioned if there is a "console" interface available.

Comment: @icarus There is a console interface available, but it doesn't work when in normal mode, I open it and it doesn't show anything. When trying to type any command and submit, it says that there's no such command. Honestly, I'm not sure I remember the password either, I kept connecting through SSH having keys locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119060/discussion-between-cezar-d-and-icarus).

Comment: Found the fix, added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the solution was a simple and stupid one.

Instead of "Use local boot" (considered normal mode, as it was and worked until this issue happened), I chose "Use bootscript" and picked "x86_64 mainline latest".

[image: Selected option in the control panel]

Comment: This is not longer a valid option as scaleway is removing the bootscript feature. https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/compute/instances/troubleshooting/bootscript-eol/